# How can I create a function in Javascript that inherits properties and methods of another function?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function:

```
function parent() {
   var address = "house";
   var getAddress = function () {
       return address;
   }
}
```

How can I make another function that inherits these things?

Comment: Inherits what? Local variables?  You said properties and methods in your question title but your function has neither of these.  You should probably be asking a different question.

Comment: FYI, this is scope nesting where a child function has access to its parent scope, not inheritance.  It's not clear to me what you're asking to do.

Comment: look into javascript prototype

Comment: You probably want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain. You can't "inherit" local variables (whatever that is supposed to mean anyway).

Comment: I would like it to inherit the local variables and function.

Comment: @marifemac No, you *can't inherit* local variables and properties.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of JS functions and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about below :

```
function otherFunc()
{
    addr = parent();
    //other stuff..
}
```

slight modification in your function to make it as per above usage:

```
function parent() {
   var address = "house";
   var getAddress = function () {
       return address;
   }
return address;
}
```